# Drawing characters using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, drawing, action

I am planning to draw characters A B C D in https://sketchtoy.com/ canvas using Selenium Action chains,

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def draw(action, offset_list):
    for offset in offset_list:
        action.click_and_hold().move_by_offset(offset[0], offset[1]).perform()
        print(f'Moving to {offset[0]}, {offset[1]}')
        time.sleep(1)
        action.release().perform()

def main(driver):
        driver.get("https://sketchtoy.com/")
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/canvas")
        action.move_to_element(element).perform()
        draw(action, [(-100, -100), (100, -100), (-100, 100), (100, 100), (-100, -100)])
```

This is the code with which I'm expecting it to draw a square shape by moving to positions similar to an X-Y graphs.

But it seems to be drawing a triangle.

[image: Triangle like image]

I am not sure how or why this is running like that.

Comment: you're giving x/y offsets from the element's position. (top-left? maybe center, I forget... or of last known mouse position...)  So when you go 100,100 it's going to move diagonally...not 100 right then 100 down... but from 0,0 to 100,100.  If you wanted to go just to the right it'd be 100,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I moved to coordinates and draw using Actions.

```
def draw(action, element, offset_list):
    action.click_and_hold(element)
    for offset in offset_list:
        action.move_by_offset(offset[0], offset[1])
        time.sleep(1)
    action.release().perform()

def main(driver):
    driver.get("https://sketchtoy.com/")
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/canvas")
    action.move_to_element(element).perform()
    draw(action, element, [(0,20), (0,5), (20, 0), (0,-5), (0,-20), (0, -5), (-20, 0), (0, 10)])
    draw(action, element, [(70, 0), (5, 0), (0, 25), (-20, 0), (0, -5)])
    draw(action, element, [(0, 60), (0, 10), (75, 0), (0, -10), (-5, 0)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a box. Move by offset is actually the distance you want to move to a side. move_by_offset(50,0) is to the right by 50. move_by_offset(0,50) is down by 50. You can round your edges off by either moving by offset or releasing.

```
def main(driver):
        driver.get("https://sketchtoy.com/")
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/canvas")
        action.click_and_hold(element).move_by_offset(50,0).move_by_offset(5,0)
        action.move_by_offset(0,50)
        action.move_by_offset(-5,0).move_by_offset(-50,0).move_by_offset(-5,0)
        action.move_by_offset(0,-100)
        action.release()
        action.perform()
```

Comment: I understand your answer. I am able to reproduce similarly but it is still confusing for me to get coordinates to write proper alphabet like characters.